# Como crear salida de varios archivos JSON con writeFile en Node

Tags: nodejs, json

//
// En esencia el archivo tiene un array

```
    [{"name":"SpiderMan","power":70},
    {"name":"Dr.Strange","power":80},
    {"name":"Hulk","power":110}]
```

// Me gustaría que lo dividiera en tres archivos, uno por cada objeto.

```
 const avengersJson = JSON.stringify(avengers);
    
    fs.readFile('avengers.json', (err, avengers) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      } else {
        fs.writeFile('avengers.json', avengersJson, () => { 
          console.log('avengers.json created!');
        })
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haria un bucle forEach.

```
const heroes = [
  { "name": "SpiderMan", "power": 70 },
  { "name": "Dr.Strange", "power": 80 },
  { "name": "Hulk", "power": 110 }
]

heroes.forEach(heroe => {
  const filename = heroe.name + '.json'
  const heroeToJson = JSON.stringify(heroe)
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, heroeToJson)
});
```

Ten en cuenta ciertos puntos:

1. El nombre del superhéroe no debería contener caracteres especiales ya que si quieres guardar cada archivo JSON con el nombre del superhéroe te podría dar error.

Ejemplo:

```
Dr.Strange.JSON ✅

@Dr.:/Strange#$%&/().JSON ❌
```

2. No parece muy eficiente crear un archivo por un solo objeto. Ya haces bien leyendo el archivo que contiene todos los superhéroes. Podrías mirar de utilizar una base de datos si lo que necesitas es guardarlos.

Comment: Gracias, tenia la idea. Pero no era capaz de plasmarla